# WPF expandable StackPanel (or something else)

Tags: c#, wpf, expand

I would need an expandable content control like the Chrome's bookmarks bar. The thing I can't solve, the button with the `>>` content on the right side. It is visible only when the window is not wide enough to show all of the bookmarks.

[image: original image: www.fixedbyvonnie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/fixedbyvonnie-chrome-bookmark-bar.png]

I think a `StackPanel` would be the best for this (because then its orientation could be changed), but I don't know how to add the `>>` button to it automatically and the contents of the invisible buttons to its context menu.
Another thing I've thought to make this whole thing with a type of menu, but I really don't have any good idea...

Thanks in advance, in case anyone have one.

Comment: The Toolbar control has this built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Toolbar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.toolbar(v=vs.110).aspx) control has the overflow functionality built in. Specifically, the [ToolbarOverflowPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.toolbaroverflowpanel(v=vs.110).aspx) that is built in to the toolbar control.  You can control how the overflow  is handled by setting the [OverFlowMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.toolbar.overflowmode(v=vs.110).aspx) property, using [SetOverflowMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.toolbar.setoverflowmode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also, if you utilize a [ToolBarTray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.toolbartray(v=vs.110).aspx) container, you can set the toolbar's orientation.

For example:

```
<ToolBarTray Orientation="Vertical">
    <ToolBar>
        <Button Content="A" />
        <Button Content="B" />
        <Button Content="C" />
    </ToolBar>
</ToolBarTray>
```